# El mensaje del to String se pierde desde el to string de la clase hijo a la llamada en el metodo

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Parte de la que heredan 3 clases, luego tengo una clase taller con unos arrays de cada tipo y un metodo que muestra los partes pendientes llamando al to String de cada parte.
De la clase padre a la hijo el mensaje va perfecto, de la clase hijo al metodo se pierde y aparece el mensaje vacio no entinedo porque. Os dejo las clases
Esta es la clase taller

```
public class Taller implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private PartePintura[] listaDPartesP;
private ParteMecanico[] listaDPartesM;
private ParteRevision[] listaDPArtesR;
private static int MAXPARTES = 20;
private int numParteP;
private int numParteM;
private int numParteR;

public Taller(PartePintura[] listaDPartesP, ParteMecanico[] listaDPartesM, ParteRevision[] listaDPArtesR, int numParteP, int numParteM, int numParteR) {
    this.listaDPartesP = listaDPartesP;
    this.listaDPartesM = listaDPartesM;
    this.listaDPArtesR = listaDPArtesR;
    this.numParteP = numParteP;
    this.numParteM = numParteM;
    this.numParteR = numParteR;
}

public Taller() {
    this.listaDPartesP = new PartePintura[MAXPARTES];
    this.listaDPartesM = new ParteMecanico[MAXPARTES];
    this.listaDPArtesR = new ParteRevision[MAXPARTES];
    this.numParteM = 0;
    this.numParteP = 0;
    this.numParteR = 0;
}

public PartePintura[] getListaDPartesP() {
    return listaDPartesP;
}

public void setListaDPartesP(PartePintura[] listaDPartesP) {
    this.listaDPartesP = listaDPartesP;
}

public ParteMecanico[] getListaDPartesM() {
    return listaDPartesM;
}

public void setListaDPartesM(ParteMecanico[] listaDPartesM) {
    this.listaDPartesM = listaDPartesM;
}

public ParteRevision[] getListaDPArtesR() {
    return listaDPArtesR;
}

public void setListaDPArtesR(ParteRevision[] listaDPArtesR) {
    this.listaDPArtesR = listaDPArtesR;
}

public static int getMAXPARTES() {
    return MAXPARTES;
}

public static void setMAXPARTES(int MAXPARTES) {
    Taller.MAXPARTES = MAXPARTES;
}

public String mostrarPartes() {
    String mensaje = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXPARTES; i++) {
        mensaje += listaDPArtesR[i].toString();
        mensaje += listaDPartesM[i].toString();
        mensaje += listaDPArtesR[i].toString();
    }
    return mensaje;
}

public String mostrarPartesPendientes() {
    String mensaje = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXPARTES; i++) {
        if (listaDPArtesR[i] != null) {
            if (!listaDPArtesR[i].isFinalizado()) {
                mensaje += listaDPArtesR[i].toString();
            }
        }
        if (listaDPartesM[i] != null) {
            if (!listaDPartesM[i].isFinalizado()) {
                mensaje += listaDPartesM[i].toString();
            }
        }
        if (listaDPartesP[i] != null) {
            if (!listaDPartesP[i].isFinalizado()) {
                mensaje += listaDPartesP[i].toString();
            }
        }           
    }
    if((listaDPArtesR[0]==null) && (listaDPArtesR[0]==null)&&(listaDPartesP[0]==null)){
    mensaje=" no hay partes";
}

    return mensaje;
}
```

Esta una de las clases hijo

```
public class PartePintura extends Parte implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L; 

public PartePintura() {
}

public PartePintura(String descripcion, int horas, Material[] materiales, int numMateriales, boolean finalizado) {
    super(descripcion, horas, materiales, numMateriales, finalizado);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
}

public int calcularPrecio(int horas) {
    int precio = horas * 6;
    return precio;
}
```

}

Y esta la clase padre

```
public abstract class Parte {

private final int MAX_MATERIAL = 20;
private static int id_partes;
private String descripcion;
private int horas;
private Material[] materiales;
private int numMateriales;
private boolean finalizado; // finalizado debe de estar en false para poder ser modificado

public Parte() {
    this.id_partes = id_partes++;
    this.materiales = new Material[MAX_MATERIAL];
    this.descripcion = "reparacion de vehiculo";
    this.horas = 5; // si el enunciado pone que sea predetrerminado 5 bien si no 0
    this.numMateriales = 0;
    this.finalizado = false;
}

public Parte(String descripcion, int horas, Material[] materiales, int numMateriales, boolean finalizado) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.horas = horas;
    this.materiales = materiales;
    this.numMateriales = numMateriales;
    this.finalizado = finalizado;
}

public static int getId_partes() {
    return id_partes;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public int getHoras() {
    return horas;
}

public void setHoras(int horas) {
    this.horas = horas;
}

public Material[] getMateriales() {
    return materiales;
}

public void setMateriales(Material[] materiales) {
    this.materiales = materiales;
}

public int getNumMateriales() {
    return numMateriales;
}

public void setNumMateriales(int numMateriales) {
    this.numMateriales = numMateriales;
}

public boolean isFinalizado() {
    return finalizado;
}

public void setFinalizado(boolean finalizado) {
    this.finalizado = finalizado;
}

public void addMaterial(Material a) {
    if (numMateriales < MAX_MATERIAL) {
        this.materiales[numMateriales] = a;
        numMateriales++;
    }
}

private String mostrarMaterial() {
    String mensaje = "";
    if (materiales[0] != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numMateriales; i++) {
            mensaje += this.materiales[i].toString();
        }
    } else {
        mensaje = " no hay materiales";
    }
    return mensaje;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String mensaje = "";
    mensaje += "*********************************************\nEl Parte con id " + id_partes
            + "\ndescripcion: " + descripcion + ", han trabajado: " + horas +"horas"
            + mostrarMaterial()
            + "\nEstado: " + finalizado
            + "\n";
    return mensaje;
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que se pierde? No entiendo tu pregunta. El haber puesto las clases completas sin especificar qué es lo que falla no ayuda a comprender el problema. ¿Qué falla y dónde?

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. En todos los casos estás llamando al `toString` de las clases derivadas dado que tus arrays son de objetos del tipo derivado, no del padre. Con lo que cuando llamas al `toString`, da igual que esté sobreescrito o no, estás llamando al de la clase `PartePintura` y ese llama al `toString` de la clase padre (`Parte`).

Answer (score 1):

He leído por encima tus métodos toString() y parecen correctos, de todas formas te recomiendo que no hagas un método toString() en una clase hija si sólo vas a llamar al del padre sin añadir nada más. Por defecto, si no sobrescribes ese método, se llamará al toString() del padre.

Para ver si el error se encontraba en otra parte, he intentado ejecutar esas clases (debido a que me faltaba el código de la clase Material y del resto de clases hijas, he creado una clase Material vacía y el resto de clases hijas son un copia y pega de la que has proporcionado pero cambiándoles el nombre).

No entiendo muy bien el propósito de los atributos numParteP, numParteM y numParteR, pero sólo los utilizas en los constructores (al menos, según las clases que has proporcionado) por lo que no deberías tener código muerto que te ande estorbando.

Al ejecutar el proyecto directamente, me sale un error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"

Al ir a ver dónde se generaba, es debido al bucle del método "mostrarPartesPendientes()", ese que recorres desde 0 a MAXPARTES-1. Este error me ocurre debido a que no inicialicé mis listas de partes con 20 partes cada una, por lo que si, por ejemplo, sólo tengo una parte en cada lista, al recorrerlas con el índice 1 (recuerda que se empieza por 0) el array ya no contiene más elementos y salta ese error.

Al cambiar MAXPARTES por listaDPArtesR.length y ejecutarlo, me han salido todos los toString() en la consola sin problema.

Igual te está saltando ese error y por eso no se te imprime nada, por eso te recomiendo que hagas un bucle por cada lista y que la recorra hasta su tamaño, a no ser que tu propósito sea otro, con la información que has dado no puedo ver ningún otro fallo.

Espero que mi respuesta te sirva de algo.